# Create CSS File from Less File

Tags: css, less, web-essentials

I was hoping to find a way to create my css files from my less files using web essentials or something of the sort. When create a new less file it will create the css to match, however on some of my older files I removed the css files permanently and I am looking to readd them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to answer my own problem. When using VS2012 Web Essentials your .less file will not compile and create the matching .css and .min.css if errors exist. My errors were occurring because some of my variables were not recognized due to the fact that I wasn't dragging in the @import of the my .less file that contained these variables. I took a quick look at the libraries you mentioned and they did look pretty cool. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

[grunt-contrib-less](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-less) is a great solution for continuously converting LESS to CSS, as is [assemble-less](http://github.com/assemble/assemble-less) (I'm a maintainer of the latter).

Answer (score 0):

It's important to say that if you installed the Web Essentials plug-in you must restart the Visual Studio, otherwise the .min.css and .css will not be generated, either.